# iOS 14, Privacy Warning , Network Blocking Encrypted DNS Traffic?

Tags: ios, network, wifi, dns, privacy

Updated to iOS 14 a few weeks back, and suddenly this morning my wife's phone is getting this message:

[image]

There is the text "Privacy Warning" next to our home network SSID in the Wifi settings, and she is unable to do anything using the internet on her phone.  If she waits a while, it will mysteriously vanish, only to reappear at some random interval.  Rebooting the phone also made it go away momentarily, but came back within 15 minutes.

Some Googling has turned up many people who have begun having this issue since iOS 14 but I'm not clear on exactly what the resolution is.  I have not seen this yet on my identical phone (iPhone SE first edition).  We are both running iOS 14.7.1.

Why is this happening and how can we get her phone stable again?

Comment: related: https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeNetworking/comments/ocw3f5/ios_this_network_is_blocking_encrypted_dns_traffic/

Comment: also, copying [this comment](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/issues/4649#issuecomment-1068649422) on github: `... from what I read iOS and macOS often bypass Pi-hole when not configured carefully, like it uses DoH if not disabled instead of the system resolver and such. `